# How to organize multithreading data storage with two Dictionary objects used as interfaces

Tags: c#, multithreading

Please suggest to me a pattern to do the following multi-threading task:

I am going to cache table rows, and need to find them by two ways:

- by Id (int)
- by Key (string)

I would like to have single row storage, and use two Dictionaries to find rows efficiently.

In the cache, I must read each row from the db and store it in global storage, and add it by key and by id to both dictionaries. I need all this stuff must work in a multithreading environment.

Can anyone suggest an elegant way to do this?

Update. My fault. I missed the obvious (for myself) restriction in trying to avoid locks because in the case of more "common" usage, when row is readed from some different source (not db) lock could lead to deadlock...

Comment: A Dictionary is not thread safe. Use ConcurrentDictionary or any of the other .NET 4.0 Concurrent Collections.

Comment: Or you could just `lock` the collection.

Comment: Good point, but I can imagine that ConcurrentDictionary might have optimized that a little.

Comment: How bad would it be if 2 threads started the retrieve-when-missing logic simultaneously? For the same row?

Comment: It is not a problem if 2 threads retrive same row, but my data containers should be filled consistently.

Comment: Yes i could use ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: Please post a example how you would expect a deadlock to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much a classic case of dealing with atomic operations. Adding an item to cache involves, using your approach, at least three operations that need to be executed atomically: retrieve data from db, store it in dictionaryByKey, store it in dictionaryByName.

ConcurrentDictionary won't help you here because that object can only safeguard itself against concurrent requests - since it has no knowledge of the fact that there are other operations that need to happen atomically, it can't help you avoid consistency problems.

The basic solution is simple: use a rwlock to safeguard reads and writes to cache. ReaderWriterLock(Slim) should work just fine especially since I assume that the majority of cache hits will hopefully be reads.

Assuming MyCache is your cache class, fetching an item would look something like this:

```
public class MyCache{
   private ReaderWriterLock rwlock;
```

..................

```
public object Get(int id)//same for the other one based on name
{
   rwlock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);
   try{
      if(cacheID.Contains(id)){return cacheID[id];}

      //item MIGHT not be in cache (not certain since we're still under read lock)
      //1. fetch from db BEFORE upgrade to write - avoid blocking all other readers
      var item = GetItemFromStorage(id);//you get the idea

      LockCookie lk = rwlock.UpgradeToWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite);
      try{
          if(cacheID.Contains(id)){return cacheID[id];}//check again!!!

          //2. insert in cacheID
          cacheID[id]=item;
          //3. insert in cacheName
          cacheName[item->key]=item;
          //return value  
          return item;

      }finally{rwlock.DowngradeFromWriterLock(ref lk);}
   }
   finally{rwlock.ExitReadLock();}
}
```

Comment: You don't show that `lock` is a `ReaderWriterLock lock;` object, which is confusing due to you naming the variable `lock`. Also a FYI, there is no `UpgradeToWriterLock(` function in the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` version.

Comment: @Igor locks do not automatically lead to deadlocks simply because it's expensive to retrieve a resource - they only lead to really long waits. Think of it this way: with or without locks, you'll still wait to fetch the item from your remote storage. If you don't want other threads to block and wait while you perform the insert in cache, simply acquire the write lock AFTER the item has been retrieved from the storage.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thank you for your suggestions - I tried to include them in the answer. I'm well aware that the Slim version requires a different approach but I believe that it is outside the scope of this question to go into such details. I provided that 'code' as an example that should hopefully point people in the right direction, not a bullet-proof, highly optimized, definitive way of doing things. When it comes to caching and locking, the simple answers are usually not the best ones.

Comment: block only cache update operation, double update cache with same value should be rare, so it is not a problem... Simple solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
private object dictLock = new object();
private Dictionary<int, int> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
private Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();

public void Add(int rownr, int id, string key)
{
    lock(dictLock)
    {
        dict1.Add(id, rownr);
        dict2.Add(key, rownr);
    }
}

public int GetRow(int id)
{
    lock(dictLock)
    {
        return dict1[id];
    }
}

public int GetRow(string key)
{
    lock(dictLock)
    {
        return dict2[key];
    }
}
```